# Using find() in Active Record with multiple where clause

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to divide (using brackets) following Active Record query in 3 groups. First group would be from first "Where" clause to last "orWhere". Second and third would be using "andWhere".

Please give me suggestions about how can I use brackets to separate all 3 sections.

```
$query = Book::find()
->where('book_name LIKE :book_name', array(':book_name' => 
'%'.$book_name.'%'))
->orWhere('book_category LIKE :book_category', array(':book_category' =>'%'.$category.'%'))
->orWhere('finance_subcategory LIKE :finance', array(':finance' => '%'.$category.'%'))
->orWhere('insurance_subcategory LIKE :insurance', array(':insurance' => '%'.$category.'%'))
->andWhere('address LIKE :address', array(':address' => '%'.$address.'%'))
->andWhere('status =:status', array(':status' => 'Enabled'))
->orderBy('book_id');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Can be done like this:

```
$query = Book::find()
    ->where([
        'or',
        ['like', 'book_name', $book_name],
        ['like', 'book_category', $category],
        ['like', 'finance_subcategory', $category],
        ['like', 'insurance_subcategory', $category],
    ])
    ->andWhere(['like', 'address', $address])
    ->andWhere(['status' => 'Enabled'])
    ->orderBy('book_id');
```

I also refactored it for you so it looks more readable now. Don't use concatenation like that, it's not good practice.

See [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

Comment: Great! Thanks. But I would like to generate Query like following SELECT * FROM `book` WHERE (`book_name`  LIKE "ABC" OR `book_category` LIKE "ABC") AND `book_address` LIKE "XYZ" AND `status`="Enabled". Your provided way doesn't show same result for my case. Do you have any suggestion please?

Comment: It generates exactly what you described. Now you show different query than in your initial question formulation. Just remove finance and insurance subcategories conditions in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed this by following your way.