# How to say (a AND b) OR (c AND d) in a YII2 ActiveRecord query?

Tags: php, activerecord, orm, yii2

I'm having a hard time with YII2's ORM, which does not document some quite simple typical SQL cases like

**Pseudo-Code**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a=1 AND b=2) OR (a=3 AND b=4)
```

**What I've tried:**

```
// should represent the commented logic, but does not
Demo::find()
    ->where(...) // ( condition one
    ->andWhere(...) // AND condition two )
    ->orWhere(...) // OR (!) ( condition three
    ->andWhere(...) // AND condition four )
```

**Question:**

In YII2, the where()-method does not allow to "nest" queries, and this is where I'm stuck. YII2 only allows to say simple AND .. OR costructs, never a set of ANDs together.

Answer (score 3):

`where()` method allows nested conditions:

```
Demo::find()->where(['or', ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2], ['a' => 3, 'b' => 4]]);
```

There are some examples in official docs [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

More complex example (as you asked in comment):

```
Demo::find()->where([
    'or',
    ['and', ['not in', 'a' => [1, 2]], ['not in', 'b' => [3, 4]]],
    ['a' => [5, 6]], 'b' => [7, 8]],
]);
```

Another example can be found in similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357583/using-find-in-active-record-with-multiple-where-clause).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
Demo::find()
    ->where('(a = :a AND b = :b)', [
        ':a' => 'bla',
        ':b' => 'bla',
    ])
    ->orWhere('(c = :c AND d = :d)', [
        ':c' => 'bla',
        ':d' => 'bla',
    ]);
```

The docs http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail give a pretty good explanation of the possibilities of the where options. Including how to use a subquery.

The **and** and **or** description explains how to create sets in a different way than shown above.

Comment: Thanks, excellent answer, but unfortunately this does support the `x => 1` syntax, but not constructs like NOT, NOT IN, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
Demo::find()->where('a=1 and b=2 or f=3')->one();
```